# Github shields.io badges for a fork?

Tags: github, git-fork, shields.io

When I fork a repo that has some shields.io badges in its readme, the shields on my fork keep representing the original location instead of my fork's status. IS it possible to parameterize the readme so that they point to "whatever github project I'm from" instead of a specific one?

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible. Badges are simple images with hardcoded URLs, so you have to run something like

```
sed -i 's|ozkriff/zemeroth|another-user/zemeroth|g' README.md
```

and then check manually that it worked and you haven't accidentally modified other hardcoded paths.